# .net core 2 form input form tag helper for bool type not generating checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a model which has a boolean property.  In the edit view it displays as a text field of type text which I don't understand.  In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it states that a boolean input should display a checkbox for the type.

Model:

```
public class Person
    {  ...
       public bool? boolprop {get; set;}
    }
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
{  ...
   <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="boolprop" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="boolprop" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="boolprop" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
}
```

Generated html:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="boolprop" name="boolprop" value="True">
```

Any ideas how you can get a checkbox to display with the input tag helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a tri-state list (not set, true, false) by doing this instead:

`Html.InputFor(x=>x.boolprop)`

A nullable boolean (`bool?`) and a boolean are not the same thing, of course. I agree the tag-helper output isn't especially intuitive, but Microsoft has said this is by design:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5667#issuecomment-271394567

> It's by design.
>
> Imagine for example what it would mean for a bool? property to result in a checkbox . How could a user choose null when they submit a form?

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even think about it being null.  I tested an example not nullable and it worked as expected.